# getting current context in the main

Tags: dart, flutter

am using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) for push notifications.. and am doing it like this:

```
Future main() async {

FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(message['route']);
   //globals.firebase(context, message['route']);
    print('on message $message');
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on resume $message');
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print('on launch $message');
  },
);
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
  print('firebase token is');
  print(token);
});


Routes.configureRoutes(globals.router);
Application.router = globals.router;

// Run app from splash page!
runApp(MyApp());
```

}

but am not able to get the context here in the main to call this method:

```
void firebase(BuildContext context, String route) {
router.navigateTo(context, route,
  transition: TransitionType.inFromRight,
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
}
```

i also tried the

> GlobalKey navigatorKey

solution but it didn't work i think because am using [fluro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluro)for navigation and routing ...

how to solve this and get the current context in the main of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use navigatorKey.currentState.push()